# Lecture notes on statistics and probability

Tags: probability, references, descriptive-statistics

Can you suggest some good introductive lecture notes, books and papers on statistics and probability?

thank you, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: The question is a bit broad... ;) What are the topics that interest you?

Comment: @Philopolis every introdutcive topics in probability theory, statistics ecc.

Comment: We have many threads that respond to this general question: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3Ayes+book+is%3Aquestion+statistics+probability.

Answer (score 1):

This is heavily subjective, but here are some books I like and I find useful:

- For a soft and very "user-friendly" introduction to statistics and R, through resampling methods, Zieffler, Harring & Long: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118063682
- For a complete tour, Hastie, Tibshirani & Friedman: https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/
- For linear models, Weisberg: https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Applied+Linear+Regression%2C+4th+Edition-p-9781118386088
- For multivariate analysis, Rencher & Christensen: https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Methods+of+Multivariate+Analysis%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9781118391679

Answer (score 1):

**In case you entertain the possibility of a video course, here is the link for an
Introductory Statistics course on youtube.**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxpc-HPKN28&t=28000s

**Some advantages of the course:**

1. It is structured like any other textbook, with time markers for each topic of interest provided.
2. One of my favorites - NO ADDs for the entire course.
3. The course is based on the following introductory textbook:
   Understanding Basic Statistics (Brase & Brase, 2012).
4. Course delivered by a social scientist, Monika Wahi.

Anyway, such a mode of learning might not be for everyone, but if it suits you, you should find it useful.

**References**

Brase, C. H., & Brase, C. P. (2016). *Understanding Basic Statistics (6th ed.).* Boston: Houghton Mifflin.

Monika Wahi's peer-reviewed articles list: https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=v3BDf1oAAAAJ&hl=en